# how can i add one feature for dataframe based on complex condition?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 'col_b':[1,0,0,1,0,1],'col_c':[1,0,0,1,0,1]})

df
   col_a  col_b  col_c
0      0      1      1
1      0      0      0
2      0      0      0
3      1      1      1
4      1      0      0
5      1      1      1
```

i want to add a new feature to this `df`,based on (presudocode)`if numbers(1) in a row are majority in this row`,just like a `voter`.  i have tried `for` on every column, but the orginal data`s rows are 10000, it takes about several mintutes( i think if use `pandas` api, it would be faster). i have tried `apply` or `assign`, but it fails because of the unfamiliarity to the `pandas`package.
i want to learn it using pandas api,thank you  all

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html):

```
df['col_d'] = df.mode(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d
0      0      1      1      1
1      0      0      0      0
2      0      0      0      0
3      1      1      1      1
4      1      0      0      0
5      1      1      1      1
```

Comment: thank you, bro.  how can i get  some useful practice  from pandas quickly?  pandas has so much api.  the problem may be ambitiougous , so it`s hard to catch the  exactly problem.  is there  a good class or book for a rookie?

Answer (score 0):

You can sum on columns, if the result is greater than 1, it means 1 is majority

```py
import numpy as np

df['feature'] = np.where(df.sum(axis=1).ge(2), '1 majority', '0 majority')
```

```
print(df)

   col_a  col_b  col_c     feature
0      0      1      1  1 majority
1      0      0      0  0 majority
2      0      0      0  0 majority
3      1      1      1  1 majority
4      1      0      0  0 majority
5      1      1      1  1 majority
```